# matchesMask must have the same size as matches1to2 in function 'drawMatches

Tags: python, opencv, deep-learning, computer-vision, image-stitching

The function is:

```py
def drawMatches(src_img,src_kp,dst_img,dst_kp,matches,matchesMask):
    draw_params = dict(matchColor = (0,255,0), # draw matches in green color
    singlePointColor = None,
    matchesMask = matchesMask[:100], # draw only inliers
    flags = 2)
    return cv2.drawMatches(src_img,src_kp,dst_img,dst_kp,matches[:100],None,**draw_params)
```

The code is :

```py
#draw matches
img=features.drawMatches(list_images[1],k0,list_images[0],k1,mat,matMask)
plt.figure(figsize=(15,15))
plt.imshow(convertResult(img))
```

I get an error with the following traceback.

```py
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-6b09780bfa11> in <module>
      1 #draw matches
----> 2 img=features.drawMatches(list_images[1],k0,list_images[0],k1,mat,matMask)
      3 plt.figure(figsize=(15,15))
      4 plt.imshow(convertResult(img))

<ipython-input-6-f486c2a7c157> in drawMatches(src_img, src_kp, dst_img, dst_kp, matches, matchesMask)
     81                        matchesMask = matchesMask[:100], # draw only inliers
     82                        flags = 2)
---> 83         return cv2.drawMatches(src_img,src_kp,dst_img,dst_kp,matches[:100],None,**draw_params)

error: OpenCV(3.4.2) /io/opencv/modules/features2d/src/draw.cpp:198: error: (-201:Incorrect size of input array) matchesMask must have the same size as matches1to2 in function 'drawMatches'
```

What is causing this and how to resolve this error?